# Swift: Cast array of objects to array of sub type

Tags: swift

Say I have an array of Animals and I'd like to cast it to an array of Cats. Here, Animal is a protocol that Cat adopts. I'd like something like `let cats: [Cat] = animals as! [Cat]` but this seg faults in compilation (btw I'm on both Linux Swift 3 and Mac Swift 2.2). My workaround is to just create a function that downcasts each item individually and adds it to a new array (see small example below). It produces the desired result, but isn't as clean as I'd like.

My questions are:

1. is this totally dumb and I'm just missing an easier way to do this?
2. how can I pass a type as the target parameter in the function below, rather than passing an instance? (e.g. I'd like to pass Cat.self rather than Cat(id:0) but doing so causes an error saying cannot convert Cat.Type to expected argument type Cat)

Here's what I have so far:

```
protocol Animal: CustomStringConvertible 
{
    var species: String {get set}
    var id: Int {get set}
}

extension Animal
{
    var description: String 
    {
        return "\(self.species):\(self.id)"
    }
}

class Cat: Animal 
{
    var species = "felis catus"
    var id: Int

    init(id: Int)
    {
        self.id = id
    }
}

func convertArray<T, U>(_ array: [T], _ target: U) -> [U]
{
    var newArray = [U]()
    for element in array
    {
        guard let newElement = element as? U else
        {
            print("downcast failed!")
            return []
        }

        newArray.append(newElement)
    }

    return newArray
}

let animals: [Animal] = [Cat(id:1),Cat(id:2),Cat(id:3)]
print(animals)
print(animals.dynamicType)

// ERROR: cannot convert value of type '[Animal]' to specified type '[Cat]'
// let cats: [Cat] = animals

// ERROR: seg fault
// let cats: [Cat] = animals as! [Cat]

let cats: [Cat] = convertArray(animals, Cat(id:0))
print(cats)
print(cats.dynamicType)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Am I missing an easier way to do this?

You can use `map` to make the conversion:

```
let cats: [Cat] = animals.map { $0 as! Cat }
```

> 2. how can I pass a type as the target parameter in the function below, rather than passing an instance?

First, you need to remove the instance parameter:

```
func convertArray<T, U>(array: [T]) -> [U] {
    var newArray = [U]()
    for element in array {
        guard let newElement = element as? U else {
            print("downcast failed!")
            return []
        }
        newArray.append(newElement)
    }
    return newArray
}
```

Since you cannot specify type parameters explicitly, you need to provide the compiler with some info to deduce the type of `U`. In this case, all you need to do is to say that you are assigning the result to an array of `Cat`:

```
let cats: [Cat] = convertArray(animals)
```

Comment: Sweet thanks, I'll try removing U and accept this if it works for me. I'd thought about map but in practice I'll throw if the downcast fails

Comment: @Philip As far as throwing on a cast goes, you can do the same thing in a `map`. Operator `as!` with exclamation point will throw on unsuccessful cast, too.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize map could take a closure that throws. And yeah, leaving it up to as! to throw could work but I'd like to have a custom message go with it

Answer (score 8):

As of Swift 4.1 using `compactMap` would be the preferred way, assuming you don't want the method to completely fail (and actually crash) when you have any other Animal (for example a Dog) in your array.

```
let animals: [Animal] = [Cat(id:1),Dog(id:2),Cat(id:3)]
let cats: [Cat] = animals.compactMap { $0 as? Cat }
```

Because `compactMap` will purge any nil values, you will end up with an array like so:

```
[Cat(1), Cat(3)]
```

As a bonus, you will also get some performance improvement as compared to using a `for` loop with append (since the memory space is not preallocated; with map it automatically is).

Comment: The `for` loop is not the performance problem. The problem is not allocating enough capacity beforehand.